# checkmarx fails for the request.getHeader()

Tags: java, spring-boot, checkmarx

When I generate the report checkmarx is always showing SSRF error for  request.getHeader() , I altered the code but still checkmarx doesn't pass this condition:

```java
String name_header = request.getHeader("name");
if (name_header.matches("(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[!@#*+_(%?/{}\\[\\].,;:-]).*")) {
    LOG.error(" Please validate the name ");
    throw new Exception();
} else {
    headers.set(name, request.getHeader(name_header));
}
```

and I also tried:

```java
String nameHeader = request.getHeader(name).toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
if (nameHeaderList.contains(nameHeader)) {
    headers.set(NAME, nameHeader);
} else {
    LOG.error("Please pass valid name");
}
```

none of the solutions I am trying is working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: And the warning you get is?

Comment: What do you mean by "checkmarx fails" or "checkmarx is always crying" ?
Are there any warning / error messages? If so, please add them

Comment: @M.Den  checkmarx fails with SSRF error

Comment: @pochop checkmarx fails with SSRF error